# access: vba code failing to compile

Tags: ms-access, vba

My access vba code has got corrupted and when I try to complile the code, I get the Compile error: User-defined type not defined. Could you please help me if there is anything which has gone wrong with the code

```
Option Compare Database



 Public Function GetFolderByName(strFolderName As String, Optional objFolder As         Outlook.MAPIFolder, Optional intFolderCount) As MAPIFolder


 Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim colStores As Outlook.Folders
Dim objStore As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim colFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim objResult As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim I As Long

On Error Resume Next
 Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set colStores = objNS.Folders

If objFolder Is Nothing Then
 'If objFolder is not passed, assume this is the initial call and cycle through stores
  intFolderCount = 0
For Each objStore In colStores
  Set objResult = GetFolderByName(strFolderName, objStore, intFolderCount)
  If Not objResult Is Nothing Then Set GetFolderByName = objResult
Next
Else
'Test to see if this folder's name matches the search criteria
If objFolder.Name = strFolderName Then
  Set GetFolderByName = objFolder
  intFolderCount = intFolderCount + 1
End If
Set colFolders = objFolder.Folders
'Cycle through the sub folders with recursive calls to this function
For Each objFolder In colFolders
  Set objResult = GetFolderByName(strFolderName, objFolder, intFolderCount)
  If Not objResult Is Nothing Then Set GetFolderByName = objResult
Next
End If
'If two or more folders exist with the same name, set the function to Nothing
If intFolderCount > 1 Then Set GetFolderByName = Nothing

 Set objResult = Nothing
 Set colFolders = Nothing
 Set objNS = Nothing
 Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

It ends up highlighting the following line Public Function GetFolderByName(strFolderName As String, Optional objFolder As         Outlook.MAPIFolder, Optional intFolderCount) As MAPIFolder

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's virtually impossible. "Can you fix my code? I won't bother to show it to you, but tell me what's wrong with it."

Comment: The compiler highlights whatever it believes is the "undefined" User-defined type.  What does it highlight?

Comment: add a reference to the outlook runtime library

Comment: Also inspect all your project's references to see whether any are marked as "Missing".

Comment: Obvious culprit is a missing reference to Outlook libarary. Try adding that and see what happens.  Without that reference, something like `Outlook.MAPIFolder` is assumed to be a user-defined type, and hence undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the compiler complained about your function's declaration, I copied just that to an Access standard module like so:

```
Public Function GetFolderByName(strFolderName As String, _
    Optional objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, _
    Optional intFolderCount) As MAPIFolder

End Function
```

That gave me the same compile error you reported.  When I added a reference to the Outlook object library as @enderland suggested, it compiled without error:

[image]

That same change may well cure your immediate problem.  However, you should also make sure there aren't other undiscovered problems waiting to bite you.  Add `Option Explicit` to your module's Declarations section:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
```

Then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  If the compiler complains about anything else, fix that and compile again.  Repeat as needed until you get no more compiler complaints.

Comment: This is a lot prettier than my simple comment that's for sure :)

Comment: @enderland Thanks.  I was squeamish about stealing your thunder on this.  If you prefer to submit the answer yourself, I will be glad to ask codemacha to accept your answer instead of this one.

Comment: Don't worry about it.